# If User exists update variables, else Create new (find_or_create_by)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, import

I'm importing Data from a CSV file (using [Smarter CSV](https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv)). I process this file as follow in a task:

```
require 'smarter_csv'

desc "Import Players from World data"

task :import => [:environment] do

  file = "db/data/players.txt"

  SmarterCSV.process(file, {
    :user_provided_headers => [
      "grepo_id", "name", "alliance_id", "points", "rank", "towns"
    ], headers_in_file: false
  }) do |array|

    # post-process the data from each row
    array.each do |a|
      a[:name] = CGI::unescape(a[:name]).force_encoding('UTF-8')
    end

    # Create Player
    Player.create(array.first)

  end

end
```

From the `:user_provided_headers` you can see what variables are passed to each Player.

The variables `'grepo_id'` and `'name'` are staying the same all of the time, but the other variables change over time.

I'm trying to `Find_or_create` or `Update` a given user. For referencing a user i use `'grepo_id'` as this variable is unique to every player.

But it seems that i'm missing something, whatever i try goes swimming and i think i got the wrong approach here.

What can i do in this Situation to:

- Find_by `'grepo_id'`
- If exists update other variables (if any changes)
- If not existing, create.

Cheers

Edit: from the Smarter CSV Documentation

```
SmarterCSV.process(filename) do |array|
  # we're passing a block in, to process each resulting hash / =row (the block takes array of hashes)
  # there is only one hash in each array
  MyModel.create( array.first )
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - i'm assuming you want to do it for all rows here, rather than the first one, but you can change if it that's not the case

```
@users = []
array.each do |row|
  row[:name] = CGI::unescape(row[:name]).force_encoding('UTF-8')
  user = User.find_by_grepo_id(row[:grepo_id]) || User.new
  user.update_attributes(row)
  @users << user
end
```

Comment: Can you explain why we need to use players = [] and players << player. It works without them too.

Comment: You could use `map` here and just return the array to `@users`

Comment: It does, yeah, but normally you might want to display the newly created players on the resulting view page, or something similar. If not then yeah you don't need to collect them in a variable.

Comment: @engineersmrsky you could but I've never liked making permanent changes inside a map block: it feels wrong. To me "map" should just be used to get data, not make updates.